# How to use a Proc as a block

Tags: ruby, codeblocks

Given an array `myarr` and a method `foo` that is understood by each element of the array, I can produce a new array by:

```
mapper = :foo
newarr = myarr.map(&mapper)
```

because the `&` shortcut turns the symbol stored in `mapper` into a `Proc`.

Suppose `mapper` is not a `Symbol`, but is already a `Proc` instance. This, then:

```
mapper = :foo.to_proc
newarr = myarr.map(mapper)
```

raises an error because `Array#map` does not accept a parameter.

Of course I can do:

```
newarr = myarr.map {|x| mapper.call(x)}
```

but I wonder whether there is a shortcut trick (similar to `&:foo`) that I can use here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do:

```
newarr = myarr.map(&mapper)
```

A `Proc` instance is an object, whereas a block is not an object. They are not interchangable. You need to convert one to the other using `&`. In case `mapper` is a symbol, the effect of `&` in `&mapper` is not just to convert `mapper` into a `Proc` instance; that is just part of the process of converting/interpreting `mapper` to/as a block. This is no different when `mapper` is already a `Proc` instance; just this intermediate step of converting it to a `Proc` instance becomes trivial.